# Sharing UserDefault between targets doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, watchos, userdefaults

Sharing UserDefault between targets doesn't work. I have set App Group for both targets but  the data is not available on watchOS. See my simplified code:

On iOS:

```swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.my-bundle-id")!
    defaults.set(true, forKey: "testKey")

    return true
}
```

On watchOS:

```swift
func applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
    let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.my-bundle-id")!
    let uddata = defaults.bool(forKey: "testKey")
    print(uddata) // Still returns false
}
```

This is the app group (which is set for **EACH** target!):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/89859):

Modern versions of watchOS run your WatchKit extension on the Apple Watch.  As such, you can’t share content between your iOS app and your WatchKit extension via an App Group; you’ll have to use some sort of networking technology.  Many folks use WatchConnectivity for this.

// I've looked through tons of tutorials online …

It sounds like those tutorials were written for an older version of watchOS, where the WatchKit Extension ran on the iPhone.  This hasn’t been the case since `watchOS 2`.

Comment: Thanks for the documented research.  It helped me.  :)